# Azure Service Principal Secret expiration in hours

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-automation

When creating an Azure Principal is there an option to force the secrets to expire in hours, I know there are options for years, months, days, but is there an for hours?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could not do that in azure portal directly, the easiest way is to use powershell to do that after creating the App, you can use both [`Az`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/install-az-ps?view=azps-4.8.0) module and [`AzureAD`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/active-directory/install-adv2?view=azureadps-2.0) module, it depends on your requirements.

Also, I believe the you just want to add the secret in `Certificates & secrets` for App Registration, not the service principal, they are different.

Use [`New-AzADAppCredential`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.resources/new-azadappcredential?view=azps-4.8.0):

```
$SecureStringPassword = ConvertTo-SecureString -String "password123" -AsPlainText -Force
New-AzADAppCredential -ObjectId <object-id of App Registration> -Password $SecureStringPassword -StartDate (Get-Date) -EndDate (Get-Date).AddHours(3)
```

[image]

Use [`New-AzureADApplicationPasswordCredential`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/new-azureadapplicationpasswordcredential?view=azureadps-2.0):

```
New-AzureADApplicationPasswordCredential -ObjectId <object-id of App Registration> -StartDate (Get-Date) -EndDate (Get-Date).AddHours(3)
```

[image]

**Besides**, if you actually want to add the secret to the service principal, use [`New-AzADSpCredential`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.resources/new-azadspcredential?view=azps-4.8.0) and [`New-AzureADServicePrincipalPasswordCredential`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/new-azureadserviceprincipalpasswordcredential?view=azureadps-2.0) instead.